# Calculating Sinuosity Using ArcGIS Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, vba

Trying to calculate sinuosity via Field Calculator (ArcGIS v 10.2.2); VBA

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
Dim dblLe as double
Dim dblLf as double
Dim dblS as double
Dim pCurve as Icurve
Dim pFPoint as IPoint
Dim pTPoint as IPoint
Set pCurve = [Shape]
Set pFPoint = pCurve.FromPoint
Set pTPoint = pCurve.ToPoint
dblLe = Sqr((pFPoint.X - pTPoint.X)^2 + (pFPoint.Y - pTPoint.Y)^2)
dblLf  = pCurve.Length
dblS = dblLe/dblLf
```

Variable =

```
dblS
```

I know ESRI has a python script put I am try to run via Field Calculator.  Anyone see my error?

Comment: Field Calculator only supports VBScript and Python, not VBA.  If Esri has an example in python, you can use that with the Field Calculator.

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Comment: If you have the link to the sample, could you post it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If done in Python:

Expression parameter:

```
getSinuosity(!shape!)
```

Codeblock parameter:

```
import math
def getSinuosity(shape):
    length = shape.length
    d = math.sqrt((shape.firstPoint.X - shape.lastPoint.X) ** 2 +
                  (shape.firstPoint.Y - shape.lastPoint.Y) ** 2)
    return d / length
```

Make sure to use an expression type of `PYTHON_9.3`.

Also take a look at this tool [here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=00e708a448b74810a0e805c4a97f9d46). I wrote this a couple of years ago as part of a demo. Under the hood, it's using CalculateField like I've described above.

Comment: Perfect...... I was missing the"!" in "getSinuosity(!shape!)"

Comment: Lately I've started to receiving the following error .... ERROR 000539: Runtime error SyntaxError: encoding declaration in Unicode string (<string>, line 0) ...... any ideas